# Как автоматизировать бэкап коллекций?

Tags: node.js, резервное-копирование, express

Решил покопать в сторону бэкапа коллекций по крону.
Возможно ли из под ноды выполнить консольную команду?

```
mongoexport -d database -c collection  -o collection.json --jsonArray
```

Поставил npm node-schedule, с помощью которого хочу бэкапить коллекции в определенные дни месяца.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вам запускать из node.js? Если что-то пойдет не так и node не сможет запустить бекап, то данные могут потеряться, что противоречит самой сути бекапов: они создаются независимо от работоспособности системы. Обычно хостеры предоставляют услугу ежедневных бекапов, входящую в стоимость. Если у вас свой сервер, во-первых, не храните бекап там же, где работают приложения. Я бы смотрел в сторону [cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Примерно. Бекап — штука непростая =)

Comment: неверное не правильно изложил.
Хочу сделать так чтобы к примеру раз в неделю нода сохранял дамп базы в определенную директорию для того чтобы я мог скачать его по ФТП не прибегаю к консольном командам.

Хостер, да предлагает, но зачем платить, да и у себя на компе хранить  лучше (ИМХО).

Конечно, я уверен что лучше всего это делать "серверными инструментами", но мне нубасу до написания таких скриптов далеко ;)

А самое главное боюся накасячить так, что потом хостер замучается выгребать все лишнее с сервера xD

Да и спасибо за ссылочку, уже читаю, вроде бы все понятно.

Comment: Во-первых, хостер не замучается — все хранится на виртуальных дисках. Он просто удалит один) Естественно, никто не даст вам доступ к каким-то каталогам, кроме вашего.

Во-вторых, у хостера бекапы явно хранить лучше: там работают профессионалы, бекапы делаются чаще, хостер отвечает за ваш бекап деньгами и репутацией.

Это вы поймете, когда ваш комп (случайно) выйдет из строя от скачка напряжения или из-за пожара. Вы, конечно, можете сделать свой сервер с хорошей защитой ото всех угроз, но едва ли это выгодно (стоимость оборудования + затраты времени).

Comment: Да ты тут написали как будто я гугл открываю xD
У меня ж маленький сайтик, база ну 100-200 метром будет. За архивировать и 20 метров слить на комп не проблематично.

   >> Это вы поймете, когда ваш комп (случайно) выйдет из строя от скачка напряжения или из-за пожара.

Ну с сервера по новый солью, какие проблемы xD

Я с вами в общем то согласен, не спорю, но не хочу я платить за то что я могу спокойно и у себя на компе хранить. А если уж база будет большая со временем, тогда да, сливать нет смысла и конечно проще будет у хостеров заказать услугу.

Comment: Бекап нужен, когда с сервером беда.

> Ну с сервера по новый солью, какие проблемы xD

беда =)

в общем, вам решать.

Ах, да, и еслиб вы открывали гугл, вопрос стоял бы примерно так: «подскажите сервер для хранения бекапов, устойчивый к помехам сети, желательно, в пределах n * 1000$», где n >= 2

Comment: @Zelta, вы перехваливаете среднестатистического хостера :) Бывают, например, такие случаи (я лично расследовал, кто и почему, а так же как были стерты логи) -  кто-то случайно удаляет ваш аккаунт у хостера (с тысячей других) и бэкапы в таком случае тоже удаляются системой автоматизации датацентра (забываются ссылки на них - этого достаточно), бывает и попроще - система автоматизации бэкапов сломалась или бэкапила кака-то криво "всё это время". И нет бэкапов... посему лучше не только надеяться, что хостер хорошо делает бэкапы, но и самому озаботиться их хранением.

Comment: Zelta, вы вырываете текст из контекста неправильно!
   
    Ну с сервера по новый солью, какие проблемы xD

Это я писал, в том случае, что если:

    Это вы поймете, когда ваш комп (случайно) выйдет из строя от скачка напряжения или из-за пожара.

Для меня тут было ключевое слово "ваш", я и предположил, что мой комп выйдет из строя, а не хостера. Ну, в любом случае две железки из строя выйти не могут одновременно, либо солью дамп, либо он останется у хостера, а как починю ПК, так и солью.

Comment: Ах да, и если б вы открывали гугл, вопрос стоял бы примерно так: «подскажите сервер для хранения бекапов, устойчивый к помехам сети (±), желательно, в пределах n * 1000$», где n >= 2.

Тут я бы просто закрыл гугл, удалил сайт, посидел перекурил бы и пошел бы на завод.

Answer (score 0):

Если кому то нужно будет, нагуглил: https://gist.github.com/lazarofl/4961746

```
#!/bin/bash

#Force file syncronization and lock writes
mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncLock())"

MONGODUMP_PATH="/usr/bin/mongodump"
MONGO_HOST="prod.example.com"
MONGO_PORT="27017"
MONGO_DATABASE="dbname"

TIMESTAMP=`date +%F-%H%M`
S3_BUCKET_NAME="bucketname"
S3_BUCKET_PATH="mongodb-backups"

# Create backup
$MONGODUMP_PATH -h $MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT -d $MONGO_DATABASE

# Add timestamp to backup
mv dump mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP
tar cf mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP.tar mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP

# Upload to S3
s3cmd put mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP.tar s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/$S3_BUCKET_PATH/mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP.tar

#Unlock databases writes
mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncUnlock())"
```